# How to fix Syslinux on USB booting on one machine, "no DEFAULT or UI" on another?

Tags: boot, usb, syslinux

I have Ubuntu installed on a 2 GB USB drive with Syslinux to boot it.

It works perfectly on an old WinXP-era Samsung laptop. It takes time, but it boots, shows a Syslinux menu, runs a kernel, and eventually gets to desktop state.

On a significantly newer regular PC box (2012 era, 8 GB RAM, Core 2 Duo CPU or something), when it finally boots (it's finicky), it boots to say, pretty much, "Syslinux (C) something; no DEFAULT or UI configuration" and the "boot:" prompt which doesn't recognize any form of typing in a path to a vmlinuz file. So... the MBR of the USB drive boots fine, just the filesystem (FAT32) does not, perhaps.

How can I remedy this?

Comment: How did you create the USB drive? Might be related to the answers here https://askubuntu.com/questions/329704/syslinux-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found or on the marked duplicate question. Could also be that you need to switch between UEFI and EFI/legacy boot modes on the newer machine

Comment: It's BIOS only; not new enough for (U)EFI. I created the drive first with Rufus, then with UUI, to the same effect eventually.

Comment: I don't see why any of the popular fixes (renaming files, folders, making sure it's /boot or /syslinux, yadda yadda) could work, if the USB stick WORKS on a different machine. The files are apparently located correctly. Just somehow Syslinux fails to... find them.